# Android String.format() Crash with no reason

Tags: java, android, string, format, android-volley

I am having a strange crash/error that happened without changing anything. 
I am using Volley for network requests and i have a separate class with my URL end points.

I am using `MY_REQUEST_URL + myparam=%s` as the link and in the volley request i am using `String.format(EndPoints.MY_REQUEST_URL, myparameter)` and when I run this request in my app, it crashes (see the log below).

What is even stranger is that i am using the same type of requests in the same app and they all work fine except this and another one.

MyClass code:

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment{
// other declarations
ArrayList<JSONObject> data;
View view 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myclass, null);

    // initializing lots of views
    data = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    String userid = Utils.getStringFromPreferences(getActivity(), Utils.VAR_USERID); // this is a custom method of getting from shared preferences, it is static in my custom Utils class
    getData(userid);

    return view;
  }

  //different methods

  //getData Method
   private void getData(String userid) {
    String url = String.format(EndPoints.URL_MY_REQUEST_URL, userid);
    Log.d("request url debug", url);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Result handling

                    Log.e("data", response);
                    if (!response.equals("") || response != null) {
                        try {
                            // response handling


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Add the request to the queue - i have a custom class for this, used in every network request that works fine 
    VolleyRequestQue.getInstance(InsuitBusiness.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
} 

}
```

This is the Endpoints class:

```
public class Endpoints {
public static String MY_MAIN_URL = "https://www.myweb.com/"

public static String MY_REQUEST_URL = MY_MAIN_URL + "scripts/getData.php?userid=%s"
// the rest of the class is all the same like stringname = MY_MAIN_URL + "phpscript.php?parameter=%s"

}
```

This is the error log:

```
 Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
            at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2490)
            at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2426)
            at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2626)
            at com.myapp.myapp.MyClass.getData(MyClass.java:1220)
            at com.myapp.myapp.MyClass$getDataAsync.doInBackground(MyClass.java:1208)
            at com.myapp.myapp.MyClass$getDataAsync.doInBackground(MyClass.java:1204)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
```

Comment: Help me please, i don't understand what it is happening

Comment: Can you please paste your code snippet. Because it looks like your `MY_REQUEST_URL` doesn't have `%s`

Comment: @Napster please check the edits, again, i had and have the exactly same methods they worked and now many of them work now except these two. I haven't changed anything, i just run the app and it appeared out of nowhere, i tried Invalidating the caches and restart but still the same problem

Comment: is `MY_MAIN URL` a typo in pasting code? should be `MY_MAIN_URL`

Comment: can you post the actual code from `MyClass.java` because what you just posted works fine

Comment: @Napster yes because i renamed it, in the code it is MY_MAIN_URL

Comment: @Napster please check the edits

Comment: What is `EndPoints.URL_MY_REQUEST_URL`? please post the code for `EndPoints.java` too

Comment: @Napster you have it in the edits, please check. The class consists only of static strings that change based on the php script i want to access.

Comment: can you make sure that `EndPoints.URL_MY_REQUEST_URL` has `%s` in it?

Comment: @Napster it has, i have tried it, even the link formats well as i print the formatted link in the debug, i click it and in the browser it works. I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: If the link is formatting fine then where are you getting the exception?

Comment: @Napster Just solved it, in the end points class as i said i used stringname = MY_MAIN_URL + "myscript.php?param=%s" the problem was since there was a lot of code, in one of my requests i had mistakenly typed MY_MAIN_URL = "myscript.php?param=%s" instead of "+" and this was where all it began to crash, thank you very much for your help and time, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

MY_MAIN_URL which was supposed to have as value: "https://www.myweb.com/" i was mistakenly giving another value which contained "%s" and this is how i got the exception and the crash.

For future people having the same problem just make sure there aren't more "%s" in the link, Log the link in the debugger and see how it shows up.

Thanks to everyone for their time.